# How can I upload Large files to Azure File share?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am trying to use the ShareFileClient classes UploadRangeAsync method from Azure.Storage.Files.Shares 12.2.0 with .NET Core 2.2 to upload a 73mb file.

However, I am receiving a 413 Request Body Too Large response. How should I be uploading large files using the Azure SDK to a File Share?

Thanks, Wade

Comment: Can you let me know why using `UploadRangeAsync` method?

Comment: To make sure that the full file is uploaded.

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: Sorry I can't this is for a client.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001985/issue-with-azure-chunked-upload-to-fileshare-via-azure-storage-files-shares-libr/61003028#61003028

Comment: @GauravMantri worked like a charm, put it as the Answer. Thanks Mate

Comment: Since you didn't post your code, let me mark your question as duplicate of the one I linked. If you want, you can upvote my answer :).